# Nested IF statements, trouble completing

Tags: java, nested

The question on my homework is:

> Write nested if statements that perform the following test: If `amountl` is greater than `10` and `amount2` is less than `100`, display the greater of the two.

This is what I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class nestedif {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int amount1, amount2;

        amount1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter amount 1: ");
        amount1 = Integer.parseInt(amount1);

        amount2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter amount 2: ");
        amount2 = Integer.parseInt(amount2);

        if (amount1>10)

        if (amount2<100)

    }
}
```

Comment: http://howtoprogramwithjava.com/nested-if-statements/

Comment: What's the problem? You already got the nested if statements. You just have to display the requested output.

Comment: You need to "AND" those together!

Comment: ...and put another if into that "AND"ed if that checks which number is larger.

Comment: `showInputDialog` does not return an `int`.

Comment: @khelwood meaning i have to use scanner class?

Comment: @GranitLahu No, meaning you have to get a String and then [parse it as an int](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers here all work, but everyone seems to have glanced over the instructions. It says write a nested if statement, which is just an if statement inside of another if statement.

You're going to want to do something along the lines of this:

```
if(amount1 > 10 && amount2 < 100){
    if(amount1 > amount2){
        System.out.println(amount1);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(amount2);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1,This is what OP needs,good job. This answer must be accepted!

Comment: wait im getting an error code "imcompatiblle types cannot be converted to string"

Comment: and ""imcompatiblle types cannot be converted to int"

Comment: @GranitLahu It's probably coming from where you're setting amount1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter amount 1:"). amount1 is of type int and JOptionPane, I believe, is a String.

Answer (score 0):

> if amountl is greater than 10 and amount 2 is less than 100, display the greater of the two.

You have to 'translate' this statement from plain english to plain Java( or any other programming *language*)

Translation:

```
if(amount1 > 10 && amount2 < 100){
    System.out.println(amount1 > amount2 ? amount1 : amount2);
}
```

or you can use the predefined Java tools which come bundled with the JRE, so you don't have to rewrite the same piece of code over and over again. This version is using the predefined [Math.max(int,int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(int,%20int))

```
if(amount1 > 10 && amount2 < 100){
    System.out.println(Math.max(amount1,amount2));
}
```

Or if you insist, just rewrite the max function by yourself:

```
public int greaterOfTwo(int first, int second){ // or simply call it max
    return first > second ? first : second;
}

if(amount1 > 10 && amount2 < 100){
    System.out.println(greaterOfTwo(amoun1,amount2));
}
```

Comment: You don't need to write `greaterOfTwo` - there is already a [`Math.max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(int,%20int)) function.

Comment: Yes I know, I rewrote it because I think it's a perfect exercise for the OP to write basic functions such as : max, min, sort, etc. when he's learning to program.

Comment: Check `tww0003`'s answer to know about your downvote!

Answer (score 0):

int amount1, amount2;
String input1, input2;

```
input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount:");
amount1 = Integer.parseInt(input1);

input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the second amount:");
amount2 = Integer.parseInt(input2);

if(amount1 > 10 && amount2 < 100)
{
if(amount1 > amount2)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Amount 1 is the greater amount of " + amount1);
}
else
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Amount 2 is the greater amount of " + amount2);
}
}
else
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Type the number greater than 10 or less than 100.");
}

System.exit(0);

}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).